# Syntax in C language

Tags: c

What does this syntax in `C` mean?

```
EventEntry tTab[] =
{
  {LEVEL, wLP0000FF00},                         
  {0xFFFF, wL0000Ign}                                               
};
```

I see just an array and something very similar to struct. So, `tTab` is an array of EventEntries, isnt it?

Comment: Yes, tTab is an array of EventEntries. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a declaration for an array of `EventEntry` objects, which are probably `struct`s with a `typedef` (although they could also be arrays).

This syntax defines an array of two items. The fields of the initial item are initialized with `{LEVEL, wLP0000FF00}`, and the content of `{0xFFFF, wL0000Ign}` goes into the second element.

This is an old initialization syntax. New and improved one lets you designate the fields being initialized by name:

```
EventEntry tTab[] =
{
  {.field1 = LEVEL,  .field2 = wLP0000FF00},                         
  {.field1 = 0xFFFF, .field2 = wL0000Ign}                                               
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that `tTab` is an array of `EventEntry`, that by itself is a `struct` with at least two fields. And

```
{LEVEL, wLP0000FF00}
```

is initializer for `tTab[0]`, and

```
{0xFFFF, wL0000Ign}
```

is initializer for `tTab[1]` Alternatively `EventEntry` may be an alias for an array with at least two elements.

Comment: How do you *know* `EventEntry` has two "fields" (members)? I don't see a definition of that type?

Comment: @EOF My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `tTab`  is an array of two `EventEntry`s.

`{LEVEL, wLP0000FF00}` initialises `tTab[0]` and the `{0xFFFF, wL0000Ign}` initialises `tTab[1]`.

This assumes the values in `LEVEL`, `wLP0000FF00`, and `wL0000Ign` are valid values.

In this context, `EventEntry` might be a struct type or an array type (or a `typedef` for a `struct` or an array).

The types of `LEVEL`, `wLP0000FF00`, `0xFFFF`, and `wL0000IGn` need to be compatible with (i.e. the same type or implicitly convertible to) the types of whatever fields or elements of `EventEntry` they are being used to initialise.